# JOIN in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-stream-analytics

I have a requirement to validate the values of one column with a master data in stream analytics.

I have written queries to fetch some data from a blob location and One of the column value should be validated against a master data available in another blob location.

Below is the SAQL I tried. **signals1** is the master data in blob and **signals2** is the data processed and to be validated:

```
WITH MASTER AS (
SELECT [signals1].VAL as VAL
FROM [signals1]
)

SELECT 
    ID,
    VAL,
    SIG
INTO [output]
FROM signals2
```

I have to check the **VAL** from signals2 to be validated against **VAL** in signals1.

If the VAL in signals2 is there in signals1, then we should write to output.
If the VAL in signals2 is not there in signals1, then that doc should be ignored(should not write into output).

I tried with JOIN and WHERE clause, but not working as expected.
Any leads, how to achieve this using JOIN or WHERE?

Comment: Do you mean that 'signal1' is the reference data stored in the blob store, or as a data stream input?

Comment: @kgalic- signal1 is the reference data already available in blob location. and signals2 is the stream data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your Signal1 data is the reference input, and Signal2 is the streaming input, you can use something like the following query:

```
with signals as (select * from Signal2 I join Signal1 R ON I.Val = R.Val)

select * into output from signals
```

I tested this query locally, and I assumed that your reference data(Signal1) is in the format:

```
[
    {
       "Val":"123",
       "Data":"temp"
    },
    {
       "Val":"321",
       "Data":"humidity"
    }
]
```

And for example, your Signal2 - the streaming input is:

```
{
   "Val":"123",
   "SIG":"k8s23kk",
   "ID":"1234589"
}
```

Have a look at this query and data samples to see if it can guide you towards the solution.

**Side note** you cannot use this join in case that Signal1 is the streaming data. The way these types of joins are working is that you have to use time-windowing. Without that is not possible.

[image]

Comment: For this I am getting below error
```The join predicate is not time bounded. JOIN operation between data streams requires specifying max time distances between matching events. Please add DATEDIFF to the JOIN condition.
Example:
SELECT input1.a, input2.b FROM input1 JOIN input2 ON DATEDIFF(minute, input1, input2) BETWEEN 0 AND 10```

Comment: Exactly, this is related for my 'Side note', this means that Signal1 input you marked as a DataStream and NOT as a Reference data. Unfortunately you have to remove the input and re-add again if you want changes to take place. So I suggest you add again Signal1 input and this time mark it as a Reference Data. I will update my answer, pls check the picture.

Comment: Thank you.. Added signal1 as reference input and Its working now.