# Stream Analytics JOIN new data with value from a database and then store in said database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I have a database that is indexed with an ID and a counter and I'm sending the data from an event hub through to stream analytics and then to a SQL database. I want to get the latest counter for a specified ID from a database and increase it by 1 and then save the data back to the database along with new the data. Stream analytics lets you use data from an SQL database as a reference for the other inputs but I can't query the database using the currently inputted data e.g.

> Get data in, look at ID, use the ID to get the current counter, and save this new data using ID and counter + 1.

The way I'm incrementing the counter is by seeing if there's a gap greater than a second between the current and last Time values. (Also if there isn't a Counter then it's the first time being tested so sets the value to 1)

```
//Finds out if there is a gap greater than a second
function main(Counter, TimeDiff) {
    if (Counter= null){
        return 1;
    } else{
        if (TimeDiff>1){
            return Counter+1;
        } else {
            return Counter;
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking that the answer would be something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Counter FROM MainTable WHERE Database.ID = Eventhub.ID ORDER BY TIME DESC
```

My thoughts are that something like this would give me the most recent Counter for the current ID which I can then iterate on to save this new data.

EDIT: I've found someone with a similar problem to mine but using blob storage instead. They join the query and the reference tables. ([JOIN in Azure Stream Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58727624/join-in-azure-stream-analytics)) This is what I need but without the time aspect so I'm trying to adapt this currently. So far I haven't found an answer for specifically an event hub to a SQL database.